# Can't change screen resolution of Android-x86_64 installed in UEFI mode

Tags: android-x86, screen-resolution, virtualization, x86-processors

I previously used `vga=ask` and `vga=<num>` in Android-x86 6.0 to set the display resolution in VMWare and now in QEMU/KVM.

Now I downloaded and installed Android-x86_64 (CyanogenMod 13), in QEMU, in UEFI mode, to a GPT partition, and the option doesn't seem to work anymore. Instead it outputs:

> error: invalid file name 'vga=ask'

There doesn't appear to be much information about this elsewhere. But I could find:

- [What happened to `vga=ask` in newer kernels?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92817/154671) (Unix.SE)
- [Grub: Legacy 'ask' parameter no longer supported](https://superuser.com/q/359132/358758) (Superuser)
- [android-x86_64-5.1-rc1.img --- change resolution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/u7A9goT-Opo) (Android-x86 at Google Groups)

I tried `wm size 1280x720` (in terminal emulator as root) and it *kind of* works. the resolution appears to change, but the display area doesn't and it becomes a pain to read anything. So I had it reverted with `wm size reset`.

I also tried `UVESA_MODE=1280x720` and it also reports "invalid filename 'UVESA_MODE'".

There's a proposed solution at the 3rd link (`debug.drm.mode.force 1280x720`) but it also didn't work.

So, how to change the screen resolution properly?

**[Update]** I tried on a new installation and the `vga` kernel option works in non-UEFI mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.

Short answer: This line should go in the bootloader for UEFI mode:

```
set gfxpayload=1280x720
```

Explanation:

> On x86 systems, the kernel will be booted using the 32-bit boot
>   protocol. Note that this means that the ‘vga=’ boot option will not
>   work; if you want to set a special video mode, you will need to use
>   GRUB commands such as `set gfxpayload=1024x768` or `set
>   gfxpayload=keep` (to keep the same mode as used in GRUB) instead.
>   (...) The `linux16` command (see [linux16](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/linux16.html#linux16)) avoids this restriction.
>
> [GNU GRUB Manual 2.02: linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/linux.html#linux)

See also, [How Do You Pass VGA/VESA Modes with GRUB2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107479/154671) (Unix.SE).