# Android x86 not change resolution on Virtualbox and VMware Workstation

Tags: boot, bootloader, android-x86, virtualbox, vmware

I installed `android-x86_64-6.0-r3.iso` and after launch I see:
[image]

I tried to change resolution as described here:

- [Android x86 Marshmallow not booting on Virtualbox and VMware Workstation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144535/android-x86-marshmallow-not-booting-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-workstation?newreg=a7568deec9f14c6a85cacc6e41f0406f)
- https://www.lifewire.com/fix-android-screen-resolution-virtualbox-2202050

Tried to set all resolutions from this menu:

[image]

Set `UVESA_MODE=1024x768` etc.

But it's only affect on window size. I always see only a half screen in bad quality.

Comment: See if this helps: [Can't change screen resolution of Android-x86_64 installed in UEFI mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180196/209414)