# How can I set my android x86 UEFI installation resolution to 1920*1080 in my VM?

Tags: android-x86, screen-resolution

How can I set my android x86 resolution to 1920*1080 in my VM?

I tried this:[Can't change screen resolution of Android-x86_64 installed in UEFI mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180124/cant-change-screen-resolution-of-android-x86-64-installed-in-uefi-mode)

but it didn't work.

BTW I have a UEFI installation

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!
These sources helped me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576471/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution-on-android-x86-in-vmware-player
- https://groups.google.com/g/android-x86/c/2u1zrTkCiU8?pli=1
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTeb7_YaujA

1. Boot into (DEBUG mode) from the *grub menu* on boot.
2. Press *enter* after the boot completes(the screen stops producing text outputs)
3. Mount your **efi** partition by running this command:

> ```
> mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> ```

(**sdax**, here x may vary for you, but for me, it was 1)

4. Change directory to `/mnt/efi/boot`:

> ```
> cd /mnt/efi/boot
> ```

5. Edit `android.cfg`, as shown in the picture below

> ```
> vi android.cfg
> ```

[image]

- Inside **Vi Editor**

i. Press 'i' to enter edit mode

ii. Press 'Esc', type ':w', and press 'Enter' to save.

iii. Press 'Esc', type ':x', and press 'Enter' to exit.

6. Now reboot

> ```
> reboot -f
> ```

That's it, you have Android x86 in your system's native resolution!